# How to sum data from two columns and partition it in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table:

```
COLA    COLB    COLC    COLD
CSA   201603    0      10
ABC   201603    0      800
PQR   201603    0      400
ABC   201603    0      1000
CSA   201603    0      800
PQR   201604    1000   0
```

and need output in following form:

```
COLA    COLB    COLC    COLD
ABC   201603    0      1000
ABC   201603    0      800
PQR   201604    1000     0
```

Condition here is : Combination of COLA and COLB as key , so print only those values which is having COLC+COLD>1000 , rest ignore

Need oracle SQL for above output, pl suggest!

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is right.  A simple way to do this uses analytic functions:

```
select cola, colb, colc, cold
from (select t.*, sum(colc + cold) over (partition by cola, colb) as sumab
      from t
     ) t
where sumab >= 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COLA,
       COLB,
       COLC,
       COLD
FROM   (
  SELECT COLA,
         COLB,
         COLC,
         COLD,
         SUM( COLC + COLD ) OVER ( PARTITION BY COLA, COLB ) AS total
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  total > 1000;
```